# MC68k assembler address syntax

Tags: assembly, 68000

I'm trying to write a program that will take an 8-bit value and write it to D0. It will then be masked into a 4-bit value. The number I get is supposed to access a number in A0 and write it to D1.

This number will be sent to an output.

This is how I'm going at it:

```
IN_PORT     EQU $FFFFF011
OUT_PORT    EQU $FFFFF019

mask        EQU $0F

ORG $4000

START:  MOVE.B  IN_PORT,D0
        ANDI.B  #mask,D0

        MOVE.B  (0,A0,D0),D1 * Problem area
        MOVE.B  D1,OUT_PORT

JMP START


ORG $5000

segCodes:
    DC.B    $77,$22,$5B,$6B
    DC.B    $2E,$6D,$7D,$23
    DC.B    $7F,$2F,$DD
```

My problem seems to be the syntax around the comment.
Nothing is written to D1 and nothing is sent to the output.

Comment: In you're question you're saying that you're accessing a value in A0. This is not really what you do. The instruction: MOVE.B (0,A0,D0),D1, is using indirect addressing for its source, i.e., A0 points to a base address, and the 0, and D0 adds an offset to it. The resulting address is where the value is copied from, to D1. The problem in your code is that A0 has not been initialized with a base address, which you have already figured out in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to add the address with the following command:

```
MOVEA.L #$5000,A0
```

This writes the destination of the address so it can be accessed correctly, I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.